# MariaDB: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection persists only for one database

Tags: mysql, connection, mariadb, mysql-error-2013

I have several databases:
   - *curr*
   - *curr_add*

and many others on the same MariaDB instance. When I submit an sql to *curr_add* I get connection and the results. When I send the query to *curr* I get the error:
`MariaDB: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

[image]

and the service stops. When I restart the service each time I want to access the database *curr* the serivice stops. This is not the case for all other databases of the same instance. The instance and databases exists since one year and I had never such problems. Is there a way to find out what is the problem and how to solve it?

Working environment:

- Windows 7
- MariaDB 10.2.6
- I entered as root: `mysql -uroot -h localhost -p`

[image]

[image]

---

Update (1):

---

I have access to database *information_schema*. For example, I can count the rows of table *system_variables*: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM system_variables`. But if I try the same with table *columns*: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM columns`, the connection will be lost (see figure).

[image]

I submit:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables`
or
`SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM tables`
I get results.
But if I submit
`SELECT * FROM tables`
or
`SELECT table_schema, table_name, engine, table_rows FROM tables LIMIT 10`
the connection will be lost.

Summary: some database disconnect the mysql-server and also some columns of tables.

---

Update (2): error informations from file .err

---

```
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-11-28 19:42:43 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 14G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-28 19:42:44 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-28 19:42:44 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-11-28 19:42:44 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=556718604758
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.14 started; log sequence number 556718604767
2017-11-28 19:42:52 4868 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 7784ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2017-11-28 19:42:52 7820 [Note] C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.2.6-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2017-11-28 19:44:08 7380 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171128 19:44:08
2017-11-28 19:44:20 9820 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2017-11-28 19:44:20 9820 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 4947968, but was only able to read 0
2017-11-28 19:44:20 9820 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
171128 19:44:20 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.6-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=65537
thread_count=7
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 136026 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7d1b9fd8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()[my_init.c:259]
mysqld.exe!raise()[signal.cpp:516]
mysqld.exe!abort()[abort.cpp:71]
mysqld.exe!os_file_handle_error_cond_exit()[os0file.cc:5209]
mysqld.exe!os_file_read_page()[os0file.cc:5091]
mysqld.exe!os_file_read_func()[os0file.cc:5433]
mysqld.exe!fil_io()[fil0fil.cc:5436]
mysqld.exe!buf_read_page_low()[buf0rea.cc:179]
mysqld.exe!buf_read_page()[buf0rea.cc:436]
mysqld.exe!buf_page_get_gen()[buf0buf.cc:4267]
mysqld.exe!btr_cur_search_to_nth_level()[btr0cur.cc:1115]
mysqld.exe!btr_pcur_open_low()[btr0pcur.ic:457]
mysqld.exe!btr_pcur_open_on_user_rec_func()[btr0pcur.cc:597]
mysqld.exe!dict_load_foreign()[dict0load.cc:3334]
mysqld.exe!dict_load_foreigns()[dict0load.cc:3587]
mysqld.exe!dict_load_table_one()[dict0load.cc:2958]
mysqld.exe!dict_load_table()[dict0load.cc:2670]
mysqld.exe!dict_table_open_on_name()[dict0dict.cc:1174]
mysqld.exe!ha_innobase::open_dict_table()[ha_innodb.cc:6976]
mysqld.exe!ha_innobase::open()[ha_innodb.cc:6618]
mysqld.exe!handler::ha_open()[handler.cc:2507]
mysqld.exe!open_table_from_share()[table.cc:3278]
mysqld.exe!open_table()[sql_base.cc:1874]
mysqld.exe!open_and_process_table()[sql_base.cc:3409]
mysqld.exe!open_tables()[sql_base.cc:3926]
mysqld.exe!open_and_lock_tables()[sql_base.cc:4682]
mysqld.exe!execute_sqlcom_select()[sql_parse.cc:6352]
mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:3448]
mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:7879]
mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1814]
mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:1361]
mysqld.exe!threadpool_process_request()[threadpool_common.cc:346]
mysqld.exe!tp_callback()[threadpool_common.cc:192]
ntdll.dll!TpPostWork()
ntdll.dll!RtlRealSuccessor()
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x78b38ff0): SELECT COUNT(*) FROM curr.patient
Connection ID (thread ID): 9
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: how long does it take to display the message in both the cases?

Comment: For query to *curr_add* 1 second (displaying result), for query to *curr* 5-7 seconds (displaying error message).

Comment: is the case similar for the root user too?

Comment: It is the root user.

Comment: here's one link
https://lists.launchpad.net/maria-discuss/msg01699.html
which is saying like key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size +  sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 601410 K. try this and check the mysql variables!!

Comment: let me know if that helped?

Comment: @krishna aryal: I got `SELECT 134217728 + (131072 + 2097152)*65536 n;` 146,163,105,792 resp. 146,163,105 k. But I think I used the wrong figures. I tried to understand what is written in the link but didn't succeed. I did a:`mysqlcheck -uroot -h localhost -p --all databases >"C:/mysql_check_error.txt"`. All databases or OK until it arrives to curr. There it gives: `mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query executing "CHECK TABLE ..."`. By the way: I don't have an error log file like `mariadb-err.log`. Does it have another name in windows than in ix-system?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "curr%" \G`

Comment: @Rick James As soon I touch the database *curr* it will be disconnected. `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "pat%"`. This will give `ERROR 2013 (HY000): ...`.

Comment: Do you know what Engine it is using?

Comment: Can you compare the database and one table details looking at info tables of information_schema or mysql db? These are the default dbs to keep database and table details.

Comment: @Rick Janes: I use InnoDB.

Comment: @krisha aryal See update(1). Obsiously, not only database *curr* is produces connection lost, but also some tables or columns of tables.

Comment: Try that for mysql batabase too. If same problem occurs, look at the mysql files and remove the files related to curr database. And again run the queries again for counts in columns and tables. If those queries execute successfully probably those removed files might have been corrupted. Don't delete those files but backup those at different location.

Comment: @krisha aryal All tables of database *mysql* are accessible, no lost connection occured. What do you mean with "mysql files"?

Comment: a) Your database has crashed. There is an error log in the database directory, a file with extension .err , which contains information necessary to analyze the crash, including stack trace (usually, unless there is some distro like XAMPP) . This error log needs to be read, and pasted into the problem description. Also b) your 10.2 is too old. Meanwhile, there is 10.2.11 out, so you should try that. With out more information, especially the error log, it is impossible to give a good advice.

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub: thanks for the hint. I found the .err-file and add it to my question (update(2)). I was looking for a log-file that's why I didn't found this file. No, I don't have a XAMPP-distro. 10.2.6 is too old? This version is from 2017-05-23. It looks like I have to setup again MariaDB. Before I do that I would be interested to know what is the reason for this behaviour and how can I repair or avoid this. Maybe someone can interpret form .err-file what is going on.

Comment: some people can interpret .err file, yes. As DBA, one should look into this from time to time as well :) My suggestion is to submit a bug to MariaDB bugtracker https://jira.mariadb.org. You do not need to reinstall MariaDB again. if you're using MSI, download  10.2.11 and start MSI and it will do upgrade of executables without asking any questions, and if needed, it will also stop and start the MariaDB service

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: I did upgrade to from 10.2.6 to 10.2.11 as you suggested. Thanks for this: it was very easy, straight forwared. But, unfortunatly the problem persists (lost connection).

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest to file a bug to MariaDB bugtracker, with .err file first . The file curr\patient.ibd is probably smaller than it should be. I doubt the knowlegde of this fact helps much, but someone  knowledgeable would take a look, and maybe suggestion something here.

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub: I will submit the error to jira.mariadb.org and provide here the solution as soon I have one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stack trace, it seems to be the InnoDB system tablespace that is shorter than expected. When the function `dict_load_foreigns()` is accessing the InnoDB system table `SYS_FOREIGN` or `SYS_FOREIGN_COLS`, it is requesting a page that is not in the buffer pool. The page read request causes InnoDB to commit suicide, because the file is too short.

InnoDB notoriously does not report the problematic file name. We should refactor the I/O code in MariaDB at some point. In this case, we do know that the problem is in the InnoDB system tablespace, because the InnoDB internal `SYS_` tables are located there.

There already exist some related bugs in the MariaDB tracker. I think that this scenario is already covered by these:

- [MDEV-13542 Crashing on a corrupted page is unhelpful](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13542) (Yes, I copied the title of the ancient [MySQL Bug#10132](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10132))
- [MDEV-11633 Make the InnoDB system tablespace optional](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11633) (This is not going to happen soon, and the design is not finalized)

It would be interesting to know how the corruption occurred in the first place. Before [MDEV-11556](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11556), InnoDB data file extension in MariaDB was not fully crash-safe. (MySQL does not contain this fix at all.)

Could it be that the files were copied at some point? A bug in the copy procedure? Or could the system tablespace have originally consisted of multiple files, but the server was started up with the wrong `innodb_data_file_path` so that the last file(s) were ignored? Everything would appear fine until a page in the ‘missing’ files is being accessed.

You might ask: How to work around this error? Unfortunately, I don’t think that there currently is any way to skip the read of the foreign key metadata. So, if the metadata tables are corrupted, in the worst case you will be unable to access any InnoDB tables. For this, I would welcome a [MariaDB bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).

Comment: I submitted the bug report [MDEV-14549](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14549?jql=text%20~%20%22lost%20connection%20persists%22) to MariaDB. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to reinstall MariaDB. When I started deinstall/change of MaridaDB through the application wizard of Window 7 it asked if I wanted to Change/Repair/Remove. I decided to repair. After that MariaDB worked as usual. That is I could submit queries without losing connection.

Upgrade from MariaDB from 10.2.6 to 10.2.11 didn't help. Repair allowed me to be successful.

[image]

Lesson learned: Before asking SO do repair MariaDB.

Comment: Would you be helpful by posting TEXT results of 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
C) your complete my.cnf/ini
so we can see current information?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hauck. Sorry for the delay. Are the outputs from global status and variables still relevant for ansering this problems although the DB was repaired? If yes, The posting has 450 respectively 550 lines. Shall I put the whole outputs on SO? Or is it possible to attach the files?