# Mysql not starting generating below errors centos

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, cpanel

Mysql is not starting generating following error. When I **moved ibdata1 file** in /var/lib/mysql directory it starts working but this removes my databases.
    The system encountered an error while starting the “mysql” service with the 
    command “/etc/init.d/mysql start”: The subprocess reported error number 1 
    when it ended. at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ServiceManager/Base.pm line 1358.

Cpanel::ServiceManager::Base::warn(Cpanel::ServiceManager::Services::Mysql=HASH(0x1107da0), "The system encountered an error while starting the \x{e2}\x{80}\x{9c}mysql\x{e2}\x{80}"...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ServiceManager/Manager/Initd.pm line 103 Cpanel::ServiceManager::Manager::Initd::start(Cpanel::ServiceManager::Manager::Initd=HASH(0x11166d8), Cpanel::ServiceManager::Services::Mysql=HASH(0x1107da0)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ServiceManager/Base.pm line 828 Cpanel::ServiceManager::Base::start(Cpanel::ServiceManager::Services::Mysql=HASH(0x1107da0)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ServiceManager/Services/Mysql.pm line 57

In log I see following errors

```
2018-02-20 11:01:55 5924 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS 
error 71. Cannot continue operation
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer 
pool pages
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic 
builtins
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 
120.0M
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 760768204742
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2018-02-20 11:06:57 6308 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0. Was only able to read 4096.
2018-02-20 11:06:57 7ff612f0e720 InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
```

Comment: While they are not necessarily the exact same problem, you might find some pointers in [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506847/mariadb-error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-persists-only-for-one-database) and [related JIRA bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14549) . In turn, if you have something to add, please comment in the JIRA issue, it might help the ongoing investigation.