# Error 2002 or 2013 when connecting to my MariaDB database on Cloud SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, google-cloud-sql, firewall

I´m experiencing some kind of network issue when connecting to my MariaDB remotely, which is hosted on a CloudSQL instance (nevertheless, I think that this is unrelated).

When I'm trying to connect through `mysql.exe` or `mariadb.exe` from my installation of [mariaDB](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=connector&p=connector-python&r=1.0.7&os=source&pkg=source-zip&m=fe_up_pt):

```
mysql.exe -h x.y.z.a -u test -p
mariadb.exe -h x.y.z.a -u test -p
```

I'm getting two different error types:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '34.105.136.61' (10060)
< OR >
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to the server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Sometimes is the first one and in other cases the second one.

I understand that both errors can be caused due a network/firewall issue, but I already tried the following:

- Adding an exception to the executables on the Windows firewall
- Disabling Windows Defender
- Adding a firewall rule to allow all the traffic from all ports/source/destination

And I'm still getting the same errors.

Additionally, I also use DataGrip as IDE on the same computer, and from the IDE I'm able to connect correctly to the database, so it doesn´t seem to be caused by the server.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: when I use telnet `telnet x.y.z.a 5432` I'm connecting correctly, so the port seems to be accesible

Comment: Have you tried this link on [Troubleshooting Connection Issues on MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/) or this related [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506847/mariadb-error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-persists-only-for-one-database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud SQL supports MySQL, Postgres, and SQL Server engines, but not MariaDB.

Additionally, you tested `telnet x.y.z.a 5432`, but the port for Cloud SQL MySQL instances is 3306. (5432 is the port for Postgres).

You should verify which type of Cloud SQL instance you have created, and that you are using the right cli to connect with it.

Comment: WoW. Was too late for my brain. For some dumb reason, I mixed MariaDB with PostgreSQL (and I know that they don't have anything in common)... I was using Postgre instead MySQL/MariaDB. Now it is working.